# Recreating a simple table from Kenneth French's website (link in the description)

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I need someone help with recreating the following table in latex:
[image: http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/data_library/images/median_me.gif]

link: http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/six_portfolios.html

Here's what I have:

```
\begin{tabular}{ l l| l }
 & Small Value & Big Value  \\ \hline
 & Small Neutral & Big Neutral  \\ \hline
 & Small Growth & Big Growth \\
\end{tabular}
```

Any help?

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should show what you've tried so far or, at a minimum, provide a working hyperlink to the site from which you obtained the image. (And, believe it or not, not everybody knows who Kenneth French is.)

Comment: Sry, I updated my original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're almost there; the missing texts can be added using a `\raisebox` of `0pt` depth and height:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
{
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{ l l| l }
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median ME} 
\\
\raisebox{-0.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{70th BE/ME percentile} & 
  Small Value & Big Value  
\\ \cline{2-3}
\raisebox{-0.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{30th BE/ME percentile} & 
  Small Neutral & Big Neutral  
\\ \cline{2-3}
& Small Growth & Big Growth 
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a suggestion with no vertical rule (in my opinion it's superfluous) and using `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Median ME} 
\\
\raisebox{-0.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{70th BE/ME percentile} & 
  Small Value & Big Value  
\\ \cmidrule{2-3}
\raisebox{-0.6\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{30th BE/ME percentile} & 
  Small Neutral & Big Neutral  
\\ \cmidrule{2-3}
& Small Growth & Big Growth 
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

[image]